# create new column with mutate from minumum value by group of another column

Tags: r, min, dplyr

I have a dataframe df and would like to make a new column populated by the minimum value by group of a second column. Prior posts do not address this issue in the context of making new columns while preserving the original rows and columns of the dataframe.

Suppose this sample input:

```
a <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2)
b <- c(NA,1,2,2,3,5,6,NA)  
df <- data.frame(a,b)
df

a   b
1   NA          
1   1           
1   2           
1   2           
2   3           
2   5           
2   6           
2   NA
```

What I want to achieve is this output:

```
a   b   Min_b
1   NA  1           
1   1   1           
1   2   1           
1   2   1           
2   3   3           
2   5   3           
2   6   3           
2   NA  3
```

Here are my attempts with corresponding output:

```
df %>% group_by(a) %>% mutate(Min_b = min(b, na.rm = TRUE))

a   b   Min_b
1   NA  1           
1   1   1           
1   2   1           
1   2   1           
2   3   1           
2   5   1           
2   6   1           
2   NA  1
```

The above gives me the minimum of column b, rather than the minimum of column b by the groups of column a (i.e., I want the latter).

```
df %>% group_by(a) %>% top_n(-1, wt = b)

a   b
1   1
2   3
```

The above works for finding the right values but does not seem to work within mutate, as follows:

```
df1 %>% group_by(a) %>% mutate(Min_of_b = top_n(-1, wt = b))

Error in is_scalar_integerish(n) : argument "n" is missing, with no default
```

Thank you for any suggestions on alternative ways to do this!

Comment: It would be much easier for us to help if you provided sample data in your question, perhaps as simple as `dput(head(df))`. Additionally, it is not clear to me what your expected ouput should look like.

Comment: Not clear how you expect your ideal output, but based on what you said I think you should use `df %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(new_column = min(second_column))` instead.

Comment: Check your package version? `df %>% group_by(a) %>% mutate(Min_b = min(b, na.rm = TRUE))` works for me....

Answer (score 1):

I figured out my error. I likely had loaded plyr after loading dplyr, which made group_by work incorrectly. To fix the issue, I detached plyr as follows:

```
detach(package:plyr)
```

My group_by then worked properly, with the following code (given the same dataframe above):

```
df %>% group_by(a) %>% mutate(Min_b = min(b, na.rm = TRUE))

a   b   Min_b
1   NA  1           
1   1   1           
1   2   1           
1   2   1           
2   3   3           
2   5   3           
2   6   3           
2   NA  3
```